# How to attach VisualVM and start profiling immediatedly with application start?

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm

I can attach VisualVM to a running application, then start profiling.

All this time while I am performing manual operations, the target application is running and statistics is loosing.

How to begin collecting statistic exactly at the same moment application starts?

**UPDATE**

With `Profile Startup` what is the way to set which class to run?

[image]

Very small cell for application setup says

```
-agentpath:D:/Apps/visualvm_138/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/windows-amd64/profilerinterface.dll=D:\Apps\visualvm_138\profiler\lib,5140
```

i.e. contains no clues to application location.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the startup profiler plugin:

https://visualvm.java.net/startupprofiler.html

Comment: Check the last version of visualvm from https://visualvm.java.net/ it contains the plugin

Comment: This version does really contain that plugin, but it does not contain "Profile" tab in turn. Sampler feature also anavailable: http://i.imgur.com/nihFZuV.png

Comment: Are you using the same java vm version to run jvisualvm and to run your application?

Comment: While running `jvisualvm` from JDK/JRE, I use the same folder, as the one I use to run application. While running `visualvm` from version downloaded separatedly I run exe without specifying JRE.

Comment: I mean I run the visualvm with java 1.8.0_20 (see visualvm -> about -> details) and the test application with the same version of java and I can use the plugin and profile the application

Comment: When I went to config file of visualvm, and set there the explicit path to JDK, I got the tabs; but still can't profile due to another reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834651/redefinition-failed-with-error-62-while-trying-to-profile-application-running-un

Comment: Also. Having Startup Plugin installed, I see no way to set application to start....