# Redefinition failed with error 62 while trying to profile an application

Tags: java, visualvm

If I try to profile application, (which is prepared under Eclipse, but running from command line) with the help of VisualVM, I get the following error message

[image]

Simultaneously, the project folder is fouled with newly created class files. Although they are already existing in `target/classes`.

The project structure is Maven's, i.e. there is a foder `target/classes` in current directory and I us the following command to run the application

```
java -Xmx16g -cp target/classes tests.Runner01
```

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

The same occurs with conventional java project too.

Below it the picture of populated class files, which located where they should not

[image]

Answer (score 89):

Here https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191297 appears a workaround:
run profiled application with -Xverify:none

Comment: The correct bug is this one: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=245522 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050485. The problem is already fixed in JDK 7u71 and JDK 8u31.

Comment: I ran into this problem with java version "1.8.0_121"

Comment: @ezzadeen You solved this problem? I am also getting same.

Comment: Problem still exists in 1.8.0_131

Comment: and with 1.8.0_144

Comment: and in 1.8.0_152

Comment: still in 1.8.0_162, to put a bit salt

Comment: I also encountered this bug, but upgrading to the latest version fixed the issue.

Comment: When I added `-Xverify:none`, the profiling tab didn't appear the next time I launched.

Comment: The bug is still present in 1.8.0_181. It disappeared with the suggested solution:  -Xverify:none

Comment: Also had to use this workarround on JDK 11 in intellij

Comment: Same problem with 1.8.0_301

Answer (score 9):

If you are using eclipse, then go to **Run/Debug** configuration.
Select your application from left side and click on **Arguments.**

Here you will see two text boxes.

```
1. Program Arguments
2. VM Arguments
```

In VM arguments, enter below commands.
**-Xverify:none**

Click on apply and then Run/Debug.

Answer (score 7):

According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/33), it's been fixed. Updating to [version 1.4](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html) solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Ran into this problem today and updated VisualVM. It works now.

Answer (score 4):

For **IntelliJ**, you can set `-Xverify:none` as follows:

**Run** > **Edit Configurations...** > **Modify options (Alt + M)** > **Add VM options**.

This should reveal a new field **VM options**, to which you can write `-Xverify:none`.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I found using IntelliJ is to compile to Java 1.6 byte code.
The menu option to do so is:  File - Project Structure, then set Project language level to 6.

This precludes you from using Java features only available with Java 7 or 8.

Answer (score 1):

Just letting others know, adding the VM option `-Xverify:none` is the recommended way as per the official [Troubleshooting Guide](https://visualvm.github.io/troubleshooting.html).