# How to CPU Profile Wildfly10 using VisualVM?

Tags: java, profiling, wildfly, wildfly-10, visualvm

**Problem:**
I have an J2EE application that is running very slow for a given task (to generate some files) using a specific data set. I decided to run the visualvm profiler over the application to understand the nature of the problem. The application is running over Widlfly 10 using the latest Java 8.

To avoid configuration complexity, both profiler (visualvm) and Wildfly server are running locally.

The first problem met was the JVMTI error 62, that was resolved using the [-Xverify:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834651/redefinition-failed-with-error-62-while-trying-to-profile-an-application) as jvm parameter.

The second problem (**the blocking one**) is that if I run the profiler when the application is deployed and running, the Wildfly deployment scanner throws Exceptions like this one:

```
13:19:04,476 INFO  [stdout] (*** Profiler Agent Communication Thread) Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol version: 15)

13:19:04,517 INFO  [stdout] (*** Profiler Agent Communication Thread) Profiler Agent: Established connection with the tool

13:19:04,847 INFO  [stdout] (*** Profiler Agent Communication Thread) Profiler Agent: Local accelerated session

13:19:15,984 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.timer] (EJB default - 6) WFLYEJB0043: A previous execution of timer [id=e6a6ea46-6c2a-466d-b767-cccc8d5021a9 timedObjectId=ecs.ecs.BatchCoordinator auto-timer?:false persistent?:false timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@142b16ca initialExpiration=Sun Aug 05 13:17:05 COT 2018 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=5000 nextExpiration=Sun Aug 05 13:19:15 COT 2018 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT info=null] is still in progress, skipping this overlapping scheduled execution at: Sun Aug 05 13:19:15 COT 2018.
13:19:16,025 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-resource") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "my_application.war")]): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/as/controller/AttributeDefinition$$Lambda$157
at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition$$Lambda$157/1799183343.get$Lambda(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition.getNoTextDescription(AttributeDefinition.java:872)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition.addResourceAttributeDescription(AttributeDefinition.java:697)
at org.jboss.as.controller.ListAttributeDefinition.addResourceAttributeDescription(ListAttributeDefinition.java:158)
at org.jboss.as.controller.descriptions.DefaultResourceDescriptionProvider.getModelDescription(DefaultResourceDescriptionProvider.java:129)
at org.jboss.as.controller.operations.global.ReadResourceHandler.doExecuteInternal(ReadResourceHandler.java:370)
at org.jboss.as.controller.operations.global.ReadResourceHandler.doExecute(ReadResourceHandler.java:173)
at org.jboss.as.controller.operations.global.GlobalOperationHandlers$AbstractMultiTargetHandler.execute(GlobalOperationHandlers.java:263)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:400)
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:208)
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:667)
at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$3.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:657)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.DefaultDeploymentOperations.getDeploymentsStatus(DefaultDeploymentOperations.java:76)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService$ScanContext.<init>(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:1622)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService$ScanContext.<init>(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:1571)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.scan(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:572)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService.scan(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:491)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.FileSystemDeploymentService$DeploymentScanRunnable.run(FileSystemDeploymentService.java:250)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition$$Lambda$157 from [Module "org.jboss.as.controller:main" from local module loader @4cc77c2e (finder: local module finder @7a7b0070 (roots: D:\jbossas\wildfly-10.1.0.Final-ecs\modules,D:\jbossas\wildfly-10.1.0.Final-ecs\modules\system\layers\base))]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
... 30 more
```

If I run the profiler without any deployed application, VisualVM's profiler starts without problems; however, if I tried to deploy my application under this state/operation mode, the wildfly scanner never starts and the application is never deployed.

So, What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: How do you have the profile configured to run?

Comment: Here is how I've done this in the past. Start wildfly using the standalone.(bat or sh) script in a command prompt shell. Create or alter the script that starts visualvm to include the jboss specific jar file. Take a look at the answer here: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/269919

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I put to work the visualVM Profiler... These are the steps that you need to do in order to execute a **Wildfly 10 CPU profile** using VisualVM (**both executed locally!!**):

1. Download the [latest](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html) VisualVM (In my case was the version 1.4.1).
2. Download JDK10 ... You will need the JDK10 in order **to run the VisualVM only**. This step is required because of this [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145964) (this was the bug that I was getting before when profiling the application)
3. Change the visualVM configuration file (`<visual-vm>/etc/visualvm.conf`) to point to your JDK10 installation...
4. Go to `<visual-vm>/profiler/lib` and copy the library: `jfluid-server.jar` into: `<wildfly>/standalone/lib/ext` ... This library is required to overcome the following error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/profiler/server/ProfilerRuntimeCPUFullInstr` (More about this error in [here](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/36) and [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=214401))
5. Next, modify the wildfly startup script to include the package `org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server` in the SystemProperty: `jboss.modules.system.pkgs`. Example: `-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server`. (According to this [link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HackingOnAS7), this property forces the wildfly to locate such package from any classloader)
6. Start the visualVM.
7. Start the wildfly server (including your application EAR/WAR/JAR application)... **NOTE**: I was running the wildfly server from Eclipse using JBoss Tools; under this configuration, my application (WAR) was in exploded mode!
8. Go to visualVM, open the `org.jboss.modules.Main` process. Then go to the profiler tab. Modify the target `Profile classes` and `Outgoing calls` and put the Classes that you want to monitor/profile (**NOTE**: For now, the winner configuration for me was: `Profile classes`: `my.package.**` and `Include outgoing calls`: `my.package.**`)
9. Hit the CPU Button, wait for the VisualVM to instrument your target classes and then invoke the code that is running slow; later, analyze the results...

Comment: It looks like the root cause could have been [JDK-8145964](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145964) - I guess these steps have helped avoid instrumenting the problematic lambda(s). I wonder if it is indeed fixed with Java >= 9

Comment: I was getting the error in step 4 (`ProfilerRuntimeCPUFullInstr` not found) and only got it working after setting the VM argument described in step 5 to `-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.graalvm.visualvm.lib.jfluid.server` (WildFly 19, JDK 11 and VisualVM 2.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

The above answer helped me, but I'm writing this in July 2023, using Wildfly 23 and Java 11 running on Windows with visualvm version 21.4.

It all seems considerably simpler now.

The most important point was to run Wildfly with the same Windows user as for visualvm. Initially, Wildfly was running as a service which connected as a domain user, while I was running visualvm as a local administrator. This meant that I wasn't able to profile Wildfly at all, even though threads were being displayed and the connection seemed to work correctly. By running Wildfly from the console (not as a Windows service) with the same user as visualvm, I was then able to profile correctly.

I wrote this mini batch file to run visualvm. This only works for me if "run as administrator". Note how the JDK is specified twice, first as an environment label then as as a parameter sent to visualvm.

You will need to change all the paths below to suit your environment.

***Run the following batch as administrator, which must be same user as the one running Wildfly***

```
set JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk-11
call D:\visualvm_214\bin\visualvm.exe --jdkhome D:\Java\jdk-11 --cp:a D:\wildfly23\bin\client\jboss-cli-client.jar
```

After this you should be able to follow points 8 and 9 from above, which are

*8. Go to visualVM, open the org.jboss.modules.Main process. Then go to the profiler tab. Modify the target Profile classes and Outgoing calls and put the Classes that you want to monitor/profile (NOTE: For now, the winner configuration for me was: Profile classes: my.package.** and Include outgoing calls: my.package.**)*

*9. Hit the CPU Button, wait for the VisualVM to instrument your target classes and then invoke the code that is running slow; later, analyze the results...*

Notes:

- Java version: openjdk 11.0.15
- Wildfly version: 23
- OS version: Windows Server 2019 Standard